# PHP escape XSS in variable path

Tags: javascript, php, xss

i have some trouble with a little XSS.

This is my PHP/JS Code:

```
$('#fileTree').fileTree({
    path: '<?php echo $path; ?>/',
    script: 'something.php',
    expandedFolders: ['data'],
    multiFolder: true,
},
    function (file) {
        alert(file);
    }
);
```

First of all, i know this is vulnerable to XSS.

the code works well if $path doesnt contain special characters.
in my case, $path contains '/somedir/customers/hi'all/orders/'.

Here is an example:

```
$('#fileTree').fileTree({
    path: '/somedir/customers/Hi'All!-e.v/',
    script: 'something.php',
    expandedFolders: ['data'],
    multiFolder: true,
},
    function (file) {
        alert(file);
    }
```

Normaly i would use htmlspecialchars() to avoid XSS, but here it will convert the "'" to "&#039" and this will break my application, because i use the "path" value on windows/unix directorys.

Anybody here have an idea how i can solve my problem?

Comment: Would you be able convert the `'` character to something else, say a pipe `|`, then change it back as required?  Might not be suitable for you I guess though.

Comment: Or is it not always an `'`?

Comment: `addslashes($path)` ?